# Overlapping table cells animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4

I made a table with custom cells. For every cell I've created an animation which move current clicked cell up. Problem is in current animated cell which has for example index row 2 and goes back into the parent cell with index 1.
I'd like that the animated cell is in front of parent. 
If I scroll table down for more than 480px which is the size of iPhone screen and then click again the same cell with index row 2 the cell will just fine overlap parent cell. Problem is shown in the picture below.

[image: Image showing the problem]

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the cell and bring it to the front in the view hierarchy. However, getting the cell is not immediately obvious: You can't call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in your controller because that will dequeue or create a new cell. What you need to do instead is call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` on the table view itself and bring that to the front before you start the animation.

```
UIView* theCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:someIndexPath];
[theCell.superview bringSubviewToFront:theCell];
```

You can safely do this for all the cells you want to animate, because it returns `nil` if they are not visible on the screen.